# Simplify the LINQ query with GroupBy method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Is there any chance for simplify this query? I'm using Entity Framework and my eyes are crying when they look at this DRY violation. Database has a few tables typical for forum project: User, Post, Topic, Category - in all of them are appropriate navigation properties.

GetMostActiveTopicByUserID returns the most active topic for specific user (the most active = the most sent posts from all user's topics).

```
ActiveTopicDTO GetMostActiveTopicByUserID(int id)
{
    var result = _databaseContext.Users.Where(q => q.ID == id)
    .Select(user => new UserMostActiveTopicDTO()
    {
        TopicName = user.Posts.GroupBy(post => post.Topic.ID)
                    .OrderByDescending(post => post.Count())
                    .FirstOrDefault()
                    .FirstOrDefault()
                    .Topic.Name,

        TopicAlias = user.Posts.GroupBy(post => post.Topic.ID)
                    .OrderByDescending(post => post.Count())
                    .FirstOrDefault()
                    .FirstOrDefault()
                    .Topic.Alias,

        TopicCategoryDescription = user.Posts.GroupBy(post => post.Topic.ID)
                    .OrderByDescending(post => post.Count())
                    .FirstOrDefault()
                    .FirstOrDefault()
                    .Topic.Description

        //and so on...
    }).Single();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why do you call `FirstOrDefault().FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: Why not put the whole `user.Posts.GroupBy(post => post.Topic.ID)
                    .OrderByDescending(post => post.Count())
                    .FirstOrDefault()
                    .FirstOrDefault()
                    .Topic` part inside of a method? Then do `TopicName=NewMethod().Name`, `TopicAlias=NewMethod().Alias` etc.

Comment: @maccettura: Because GroupBy returns IEnumerable<IGrouping>> - I want to get first element from the first, the largest, group. This is equivalent to the topic with the mosts posts count for specific user. A bit strange but I have no idea how to write it more clean.

Comment: @Sach - Entity Framework don't like external methods and throws exception.

Comment: Oh I missed the `EF` part, sorry. Should have read the question properly. Still, probably a good idea to tag #entityframework.

Comment: Good idea, done. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You full group by is based on Topic.ID then you don't need to group again and again. Please do one grouping and return result like below,

```
CHANGE_TYPE_TO_TYPE_OF_RETURN-TYPE GetMostActiveTopicByUserID(int id)
{
    return _databaseContext.Users
        .Where(q => q.ID == id)
        .Select(user => 
        {
            user.Posts.GroupBy(post => post.Topic.ID)
                .OrderByDescending(post => post.Count())
                .FirstOrDefault()
        })
        .Single();
}
```

Then from the returned result you can construct your object

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you.